# create large sparse matrix with 0s and 1s

Tags: matlab

I have the following code but I have to run it for n>10^6. For n=10^5 the memory is over. I have 16gb. Is there any efficient way to do this?

```
     n = 10^6;  
     m = n/2;  
     H = sparse(m,n);   
     parfor jj=1:n                   
         pos = sample(cumulative);   
         H(:,jj) = (rand(m,1) > 1 - degrees(pos)/m);
     end
```

Comment: what's `sample(cumulative);  ` ?

Comment: What fraction of the matrix will be filled with 1s? And what is your application? Not sure if this code can be made faster, but maybe your problem can be solved in a different way.

Comment: btw - a fully populated sparse matrix occupies 3x the space

Comment: thanks for the answers. I don't mind about 0s. I care only for 1s. Every column will have from 2 to max ~=100 1s. sample(cumulative) is a function. Every time degrees(pos)/m is a different number.

Comment: Does it work in a regular `for` loop?  Also, an alternative assignment would be `H((rand(m,1) > 1 - degrees(pos)/m),jj) = 1;` but I think that will not make any difference.